# Question on when to accept the null hypothesis?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

So to accept the null hypothesis $H_0: \theta = 0$, I know that the confidence interval has to contain 0 for any confidence level $1-\alpha$ but I am looking for a way to explain it more rigorously? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you should say *not reject* the null hypothesis, rather than *accept* the null hypothesis.

I suspect your definition of the confidence interval is something like saying that, on the assumption that the null hypothesis $H_0: \theta = 0$ is true, the probability that the confidence interval for $\theta$ contains $0$ is $1-a$.

So the probability of erroneously rejecting the null hypothesis $H_0: \theta = 0$ when it is true, on the grounds the confidence interval does not contain $0$, is $\alpha$.